# Add custom array subscript accessor to class in Java?

Tags: java, syntax, operator-overloading

In Python, you can add list subscripts to be accessors to data structures for custom classes:

```
class customFile:
    # other methods ...
    def __getitem__(self, x):
        return self.list[x]
```

to get the behavior of:

```
newFile = customFile()
newFile.list[1] = 4
newFile.list[1]
# 4
newFile[1]
# 4
```

Is there any way to add something like this to custom classes in Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent in Java. The closest equivalent would be to provide your own implementation of the [List](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) collection type. Typically, you extend `AbstractList`, and provide the `get(int)` and `size()` methods, giving you complete control over the content and size of the list.